# Export sql server database to remote

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I have a bak file of sql server database about 1GB size.I need to upload this file to remote sql server.How can i do this? Or is there any way to transfer sql server database to remote sql server.

Please help!

Comment: that's a vague question. it's a one time only operation? or maybe you mean 'i need to keep the 2 dbs in sync'? moreover this is not a programming question, it is better suited on serverfault or dba.

Comment: I have tried via export data from local, but haven't worked.How can i upload bak file to remote using sql server management studio 2014?

Comment: It depends on the version of SQL Server you're using. For instance, if you have access to SSIS you can transfer from one to the other within SQL Management Studio

Comment: What error did you get when you tried "export data from local"?

Comment: you cannot use this wizard to move databases between local instances of sql server.This is the error i got when i tried to deploy to remote server

Answer (score 0):

Put the .bak file on a thumbdrive or other portable media, and carry it over to the remote server and load it onto that server.   Then restore the database from the .bak file.

Comment: i don't have access to remote server, is there any other way?

Comment: Well you can put the .bak file anywhere that both servers can access.. even a cloud drive.   Then download the .bak file to the remote server and restore it.